# Error 9 : subscript out of range Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to define the Range via some value in sheet, but i am unable to do this. Also i am not sure what causing this issue.

**My Code**

```
   Dim row As Range
For Each row In [table2].Rows

For Each c In Worksheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value)
.Range((row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("RangeBegin").Index).Value) 
+ ":" + 
(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("RangeEnd").Index).Value))

  If c.Value = "O" Then
     Sheets("master").Cells(2, 3).Copy
     Sheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Select
     c.Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
```

[image]

Comment: the error is due to Worksheets(x) does not exist because the x being calculated exceed the number of sheets in your workbook.

Comment: Its working fine when i define range as Range("A1:H100")

Comment: I am not sure what `row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value` does but try `For Each c in Range(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value)`

Comment: Worksheets is not a range object

Comment: i think i know what you are trying to do... hang on

Comment: I am trying to define range from a table in Excel

Comment: It would help if you posted the complete sub or function.  What does row reference?

Comment: It looks like row references each row in the first `For Each` loop.

Comment: What should your expected outcome look like?

Comment: What i am trying to achieve here is to to define .Range(A1:H100) from a table in excel

Comment: So you just want to print `.Range(A1:H100)` somewhere? Or use it in more code? Still not fully comprehending.

Comment: I use it in code, i am letting the user decide the range, by a creating a sheet named master

Comment: Without any further explanation, it sounds like you just need to use @Rosetta's code, change `ListColumns("Sheet")` to `ListColumns("RangeBegin")` and concatenate with `Offset(0,1)`. But I don't know. Also, you don't need to copy and paste. Just make the ranges equal to each other. And don't use select.

Comment: looking at your code, your object call method is very mixed up. e.g. `row.columns()` call doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each c In Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).ListColumns("Sheet").DataBodyRange

    'some code here...

Next c
```

`Worksheets(1)` is just an illustration. You can replace the 1 with the name of your worksheet e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

`ListObjects(1)` is just an illustration. You can replace the 1 with the name of the table e.g. `ListObject("Table1")`. If the worksheet has only one table, you can leave it as 1.

---

here is how to pick range in table row

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As ListRow
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Set lo = Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)
    For Each r In lo.ListRows

        Debug.Print r.Range(1, lo.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value

    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: how to pick up range from it,

Comment: For Each c In Worksheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Range((row.ListObject.ListColumns("range").Index).Value)

Comment: Getting Subscript out of range (range has value A1:H100 in excel)

Comment: I have answered my own question, Kindly review if i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

I refactored you code.  I think it's pretty close to what you want.
Notice how I extract he variables from your chained objects.  This is done to make the code more readable, robost and above all much easier to debug. 
If **"Set targetRange"** breaks the code I can hover the mouse over SheetName, RangeBegin and RangeEnd to find their respective values.

```
SheetName = .ListColumns("Sheet").DataBodyRange(i)
RangeBegin = .ListColumns("RangeBegin").DataBodyRange(i)
RangeEnd = .ListColumns("RangeEnd").DataBodyRange(i)
Set targetRange = getTargetRange(SheetName, RangeBegin, RangeEnd)
```

```js
Public Sub ProcessWorkSheets()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim SheetName As String, RangeBegin As String, RangeEnd As String
    Dim targetRange As Range

    Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")
    With tbl
        For i = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
            SheetName = .ListColumns("Sheet").DataBodyRange(i)
            RangeBegin = .ListColumns("RangeBegin").DataBodyRange(i)
            RangeEnd = .ListColumns("RangeEnd").DataBodyRange(i)
            Set targetRange = getTargetRange(SheetName, RangeBegin, RangeEnd)

            If Not targetRange Is Nothing Then
                With Worksheets(SheetName)
                    For Each c In targetRange
                        If c = "O" Then c = Sheets("master").Cells(2, 3)
                    Next
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With

End Sub

Public Function getTargetRange(SheetName As String, RangeBegin As String, RangeEnd As String) As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set getTargetRange = Worksheets(SheetName).Range(RangeBegin & ":" & RangeEnd)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function hasWorkSheet(SheetName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Call Worksheets(SheetName).Name
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        hasWorkSheet = False
    Else
        hasWorkSheet = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

You don't have to Select or Active Ranges.  It is better to work directly with the Range objects and not with the Select or Active objects. Knowing that we can remove any active or select lines; combining multiple operations with a single action. 
**Updated Refactor:**

```js
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True 'I Don't this line is needed

Dim row As Range
For Each row In [table2].Rows

    For Each c In Worksheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Range(row.Value2(1, 2))
        If c.Value = "O" Then
            Sheets("master").Cells(2, 3).Copy c
        ElseIf c.Value = "G" Then
            Sheets("master").Cells(3, 3).Copy c
        ElseIf c.Value = "R" Then
            Sheets("master").Cells(4, 3).Copy c
        End If
    Next c

Next
```

Comment: thanks for such an detailed answer, however i had a look on it just now. I figured out an alternate way, maybe i am wrong. It would be great if u can just review it

Answer (score 0):

OK, Finally after a lot of hit and trials, I have achieved this without much changing my code. I am trying to read each cell and paste content of some other cell if the condition is satisfied

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True

Dim row As Range
For Each row In [table2].Rows

For Each c In Worksheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Range(row.Value2(1, 2))
  If c.Value = "O" Then
     Sheets("master").Cells(2, 3).Copy
     Sheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Select
     c.Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

  ElseIf c.Value = "G" Then
     Sheets("master").Cells(3, 3).Copy
     Sheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Select
     c.Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

  ElseIf c.Value = "R" Then
     Sheets("master").Cells(4, 3).Copy
       Sheets(row.Columns(row.ListObject.ListColumns("Sheet").Index).Value).Select
     c.Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
  Else
      c.Value = c.Value
  End If
  Next c

 Next
```